How do you do continuous Java sound updates?
I have this piece of code for a video game that updates the gain for a music loop based on how far away the player is from the end door. EDIT - Updated this code with gainControl as an instance variable and with fixed gain value
    public void updateMusic()
    {
        int endX = currentMap.getEndPointX() * TILE_WIDTH;
        int endY = currentMap.getEndPointY() * TILE_HEIGHT;
        
        double dist = Math.hypot(endX - playerX, endY - playerY);
        
        if(dist < 300)
        {
            double gain = 600 / dist;
            
            gainControl.setValue(Math.min(0, Math.max(gainControl.getMinimum(), (float) (-22 + gain))));
        }
        else
        {
            gainControl.setValue(-20f);
        }
        
    }
    

The gain of the audio is updated, but very choppy. I have a loop that updates it 10 times a second, but instead of updating continuously, it will suddenly jump/drop in gain randomly. Is there a way to force the audio system to update? Or is this the wrong way to do dynamic audio like this?
Edit - Here are other methods I'm using as well as relevant variable declarations at the top

    Clip runningClip;
    Clip walkingClip;
    Clip raveLoop;
    FloatControl gainControl;
    private AudioInputStream audioStream;

    private Clip playSound(String soundName)
    {
        File file = new File("src/ninja/sounds/" + soundName + ".wav");
        try
        {
            audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioStream);
            
            clip.start();
            
            return clip;
        }
        catch(IOException | UnsupportedAudioFileException | LineUnavailableException  error)
        {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return null;
    }

    private void startMusic()
    {
        raveLoop = playSound("bass_rave_loop");
        raveLoop.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        
        gainControl = (FloatControl) raveLoop.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
        gainControl.setValue(-20.0f);
    }


Are you using Swing or JavaFX for the video game?  Here's the Oracle sound tutorial.

Side note: for performance you might want to put FloatControl gainControl = (FloatControl) raveLoop.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN); with the rest of the declarations. (Outside of the if statement)

@GilbertLeBlanc I'm using Swing for the video game and java.sound.sample for the sound

@synnøve I tried this but the problem is still persisting. I'll add all of the methods I'm using as well as variable declaration to the original post

Have you tried displaying your 'dist' variable over the screen see if it's calculated well regarding your position from the end door ?

Or maybe the gain is updated only at the end of a loop, how long is the clip ?

@madgangmixers I displayed the dist variable and it's calculating it fine. I thought it may only update at the end of loop too but the loop is 15 seconds and it definitely updates faster than that, but not as fast as I'm actually updating it. I even tried to displaying the actual value of the gainControl to see if that wasn't updating fast enough but it was updating fine. It seems like it must be the actually audio processing system that's lagging behind
